# Torque due to a small block inside a cylinder on an inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

If I have a small block inside a cylinder on a inclined plane. What is the torque on the cylinder due to the friction between the small block and the cylinder? It is easy if the center of the cylinder (circle) is used as pivot point. But what if the pivot point is chosen to be the contact point between cylinder and the inclined plane? I don't know how to find the arm of the friction force.

[image]

Comment: Use the usual definition of torque : the magnitude of force times the perpendicular distance between the line of force and the pivot point.

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to find the *moment arm* $h$ of the force (blue line below)

[image: geometry]

Can you find it from the trigonometry I have sketched above?

> $h =R - R \cos \theta $

Then torque would be $\tau = h \, F$.